# Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

How can I access the Error.code property?
I get a Typescript error because the property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.

```
this.authCtrl.login(user, {
   provider: AuthProviders.Password,
   method: AuthMethods.Password
}).then((authData) => {
    //Success
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error); // I see a code property
   console.log(error.code); //error
})
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The real issue is that the Node.js definition file isn't exporting a proper Error definition. It uses the following for Error (and doesn't export this):

```
interface Error {
    stack?: string;
}
```

The actual definition it exports is in the NodeJS namespace:

```
export interface ErrnoException extends Error {
    errno?: number;
    code?: string;
    path?: string;
    syscall?: string;
    stack?: string;
}
```

So the following typecast will work:

```
.catch((error: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.code);
})
```

This seems like a flaw in Node's definition, since it doesn't line up with what an object from new Error() actually contains. TypeScript will enforce the interface Error definition.

Comment: Not a full solution. A full solution would also show the import statement that needs to be added in order to "have" the `NodeJS` symbol.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski This answer worked great for me, no additional `import` needed.

Answer (score 5):

You have to cast a type to the error param from catch i.e.

```
.catch((error:any) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.code);
});
```

or you can access the code property directly in this manner

```
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error['code']);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained by @Brent in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562477 this problem is caused by an incomplete type definition in the Typescript package (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ed6889cd5b61b9fa5156018362d867def18e281d/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1039-L1043). People using ECMAScript 2015, or later, can also use [module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) to declare the missing properties. This can be done by placing the following code inside the `@types/global.d.ts` file.

```
declare interface Error {
  name: string
  message: string
  stack?: string
  code?: number | string
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
export default class ResponseError extends Error {
    code: number;
    message: string;
    response: {
        headers: { [key: string]: string; };
        body: string;
    };
}
```