# Typescript error when adding property to Error object "Property ... does not exist on type 'Error'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

I'm trying to move to typescript with my Node/Express app. Previously my code was:

```js
//app.js
const error = new Error('Not Found');
error.status = 404;
```

When I try this:

```js
//app.ts
const error = new Error('Not Found');
error.status = 404; // Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'.ts(2339)
```

I understand from [developer.mozilla.org documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error) that the Error constructor has the following optional parameters: `message`, `options`, `fileName`, `lineNumber` - so I guess `status` shouldn't be permitted? I think I've copied it from a youtube tutorial so I guess it's not actually good practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I think that is a different use case, because that is essentially about modifying global scope.

Comment: @H.B. I think it's the same use case, as it's about adding a property to a built-in type. But take your pick: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+typescript+Property+does+not+exist+on+type. There's 46k entries there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The difference is that with a global you would want to adjust the type information to accommodate the property everywhere whereas here is a special kind of class instance where you usually do not want to affect all instances of that class. But yes, there are probably tons of duplicates that would fit this question.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey - I've posted my own solution which is specifically for handling 404 error codes. I assume the solutions you've linked to would work for a more general use case.

Comment: The question is posed as "how do I fix the TypeScript error" rather than "how do I return a 404 status using express". Had it been the latter, I would have pointed you to [How to programmatically send a 404 response with Express/Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8393275/215552)

Comment: @H.B. Perhaps [Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141005/215552)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Does not look like it. That seems to be about wrong type declarations/exports ("The real issue is that the Node.js definition file isn't exporting a proper Error definition"). There appear to be quite a few different reasons people get this error, e.g. if an API only supplies a parent type (e.g. `HTMLElement`) but people want to access a property of a specific sub-type (`HTMLInputElement.value`).

Comment: @HereticMonkey you are correct. I don't know what the solution is here. The problem is that in a situation where I don't understand the problem/solution I can only quote the error message and hope a solution arrives. At least if anyone finds their way here with a similar issue to me then they can use my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the [expressjs.com documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html) there is a section on "How do I handle 404 responses?", where they provide this example:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```

So I've produced this and it has stopped the error:

```js
import express, {NextFunction, Request, Response} from "express";

const app = express();
...

app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!");
});

export { app };
```

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript does not allow adding unknown properties. There are ways to define objects with arbitrary keys (e.g. `Record`).

In this case you could create your own subclass to Error which includes the `status` property.

```
class StatusError extends Error {
  status: number | undefined;
}

const e = new StatusError('Not found');
e.status = 404;
```

You could also add it to the constructor, then you can confidently remove the `undefined`.

```
class StatusError extends Error {
  constructor(public status: number, message?: string) {
    super(message)
  }
}

const e = new StatusError(404, 'Not found');
```

Comment: Or `status?: number;`

Comment: This is one of the most common errors in TypeScript. Do we need yet another Q&A pair on the subject?

Comment: Thanks @H.B. I've posted a solution that's fixed the problem for me, but assume yours would have worked as a viable alternative, and will hopefully help others in a similar situation!